# Singleton class без возможности повторной инициализации в Python

Tags: python, наследование, singleton

Мне нужно сделать класс, который будет работать как Singleton и который должен унаследовать от базового класса. Классов подобных MyClass может быть несколько.

В конце концов, я пришёл к следующему решению:

```
import random


class Singleton(object):
    _instances = {}

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = super(Singleton, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instances[cls]


class BaseClass(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.value = random.random()
        self.data = data

    def asfaa(self):
        pass


class MyClass(BaseClass, Singleton):
    def __init__(self, data=3):
        super().__init__(data)
        self.a = random.random()

class MyClass1(BaseClass, Singleton):
    def __init__(self, data=3):
        super().__init__(data)
        self.a = random.random()


inst1 = MyClass(3)
inst2 = MyClass(5)
```

Всё работает как нужно если  `def __init__(self, data=3)` в MyClass не принимает аргументов и выглядит следующим образом: `def __init__(self)`
Если же я предоставляю аргументы в `__init__` как в примере выше , то получаю следующую ошибку.

```
line 9, in __new__
cls._instances[cls] = super(Singleton, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: object.__new__() takes exactly one argument (the type to instantiate)
```

Каким образом можно передать аргументы в MyClass и ему подобные? И в чем проблема?

---

После ответа **splash58** удалось получить вот такой вот работающий результат:

```
import random


class Singleton(object):
    _instances = {}

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = super(Singleton, cls).__new__(cls)
        return cls._instances[cls]


class BaseClass(object):
    def __init__(self, data: int):
        self.value = random.random()
        self.data = data

    def asfaa(self):
        pass


class MyClass(BaseClass, Singleton):
    def __init__(self, data=0):
        if not hasattr(self, '_is_initialized'):
            super().__init__(data)
            self.a = random.random()
            self._is_initialized = True


class MyClass1(BaseClass, Singleton):
    def __init__(self, data=0):
        if not hasattr(self, '_is_initialized'):
            super().__init__(data)
            self.a = random.random()
            self._is_initialized = True


inst = MyClass(1)
print(inst, inst.a, inst.data)
inst1 = MyClass(1234)
print(inst1, inst1.a, inst1.data)

inst2 = MyClass1(123)
print(inst2, inst2.a, inst2.data)
```

Результат исполнения:

```
<__main__.MyClass object at 0x7fd702199890> 0.40160478301994584 1
<__main__.MyClass object at 0x7fd702199890> 0.40160478301994584 1
<__main__.MyClass1 object at 0x7fd7021998d0> 0.6368002566047511 123
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поскольку Singleton производный класс от Object, вам совсем не надо передавать данные выше, инит в BaseClass их все равно получит. напишите просто

```
cls._instances[cls] = super(Singleton, cls).__new__(cls)
```

и после

```
inst1 = MyClass(3)
inst2 = MyClass(5)
```

получите

```
>>> inst1 == inst2
True
>>> inst1.data
5
```